# authentication using azure adfs for accessing power bi api for reports

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, adfs

For accessing power bi reports we need to generate access token.
We need to silent authentication for generating access token using user credentials.We are able to generate access token for user id's whose domains does not linked with federated active directories.we are not able to generate access token with user id's whose domains linked with ADFS.How can we generate access token silently for ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of ADFS?

Both ADFS 3.0 (limited) and ADFS 4.0 have OAuth support so you follow the normal flow to get an access token.

Comment: Currently we are generating access token by making a post request to the below URL with out prompting login screen,                           
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantIdHere}/oauth2/token'. If we try same with users (whose domains are linked with ADFS) we are getting bad request response with response code as 400.

Comment: For Normal AD, we are forming request with login.onmicrosoftonline.com base url and in body we are passing user credentilas and client id and client secret.

For ADFS, how we need to prepare request and body to get the access token. We need access token without prompting the login window. Is it possible to get an access token without prompt? If yes,how to acheive that?

Comment: Use the client credentials flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs